# jQuery daterange picker

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I want my daterange picker to return a list of events based off of the date range that is submitted from the user but right now when the user selects a date range and hits apply nothing is returned.

here is my current code:

```
<script>
        $( function() {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                opens: 'left'
            }, function(start, end, label) {
                console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            });
   
            $(".date").daterangepicker({
              onSelect: function() {
                display({events});
                $(this).change();
              }
            }).on("change", function() {
              display({event_list});
            });
          
        });
    </script>
```